# UITableView Custom Cell Throwing SIGABRT Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitableview

I am trying to create a custom cell for my UITableView. I am using Xcode 4.2 and using the storyboard along with ARC.

I have created a class to represent the custom cell like so:

**ResultsCustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ResultsCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *customLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* customLabel;

@end
```

**ResultsCustomCell.m**

```
#import "ResultsCustomCell.h"

@implementation ResultsCustomCell

@synthesize customLabel;

@end
```

I have then implemented the UITableView method in my view controller as follows:
**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ResultsCustomCell.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// Set the number of items in the tableview to match the array count
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return 5;
}

// Populate TableView cells with contents of array.
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    ResultsCustomCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    myCell.customLabel.text = @"helloWorld";

    return myCell;
}

// Define height for cell.
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

@end
```

The application builds successfully but then crashes instantly and give me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

What part am I missing out?

Comment: If you are using iOS 5 check also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016331/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-error-in-my-uitableview-in-ios5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what I have done to resolve my problem but It is now working correctly.

Here is what I currently have in my ViewController.m

Note: The ResultsCustomCell.h and .m are the same as above.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ResultsCustomCell.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
}

// Set the number of items in the tableview to match the array count
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return 5;
}

// Populate TableView cells with contents of array.
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Make sure there are no quotations (") around the cell Identifier.
    ResultsCustomCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    myCell.customLabel.text = @"helloWorld";

    return myCell;
}

// Define height for cell.
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

@end
```

I then made sure the following things where correct:

- The table view cell has the correct custom class (ResultsCustomCell).
- The cell Identifier for the UITableViewCell was correct in Interface Builder.
- The UILabel in interface builder was correctly linked to the IBOutlet.
- The UITableView view had the correct controller (ViewController)

After using this code and checking all of the above it appears to work.

Answer (score 21):

This is an irritating problem because the debugger gives you no clue as to what happened. It will break on the exception and then simply shut down if you click Continue Execution.

This drove me nuts for 30 minutes until I right clicked on a UILabel in the custom cell that was giving me problems, which revealed the answer: One of the controls in your cell has (or had, as you apparently fixed it, perhaps without noticing) a spurious outlet. By "spurious outlet" I mean one that is wired to an IBOutlet property that no longer exists in your class. In my case I had changed the name of the property and rewired it, but had forgotten to remove the old referencing outlet connection.

As soon as I removed the offending outlet the problem went away.

Comment: Sheesh. I can't believe I just did that. Thank goodness your answer popped up. Thanks!

Comment: These get me every time!

Comment: Very useful answer. Unexpected!

Comment: 2019 and still the same issues with storyboard ^^

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to create a new `UITableViewCell` when it's not dequeued

```
// Populate TableView cells with contents of array.
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    ResultsCustomCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    myCell.customLabel.text = @"helloWorld";

    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: You don't do this with storyboard, the dequeue method will create and return a cell for you if there isn't one there.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to add the reuse identifier ("CellIdentifier") in the storyboard against your prototype cell, so when it tries to create a new cell, there is no prototype with that identifier in the storyboard, and it returns `nil`.

Comment: I have placed the reuse identifier (CellIdentifier) and I am still  receiving this error.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, does it get called? Have you set the custom class of your table view controller to `ViewController` in the storyboard? If you haven't, you will be calling the base implementation of cellForRow... which does nothing.

Comment: Yep I have set the custom class correctly on the tableView controller. I also placed a breakpoint and it appears the cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called correctly. The method fails on the line. `myCell.customLabel.text = @"helloWorld";`

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* customLabel;
```

Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) forbids the explicit call of `retain`. Try to remove this.

As for the error, you do return a `UITableViewCell`, not your custom cell. Additionally, you never allocate your `ResultsCustomCell`.

```
- (ResultsCustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    ResultsCustomCell *cell = (ResultsCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ResultsCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Furthermore, your subclass of `UITableViewCell` does not declare the (obviously obligatory) method `init`.

ResultsCustomCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ResultsCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

ResultsCustomCell.m:

```
#import "ResultsCustomCell.h"

@implementation ResultsCustomCell

@synthesize myLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**EDIT:** I saw, that you are using storyboard. My suggestion might or might not be of help to you. I have never used storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I was also fighting this error with the same setup as yours. I realized that it, for me, was caused by the new "Auto layout" feature of iOS6. To disable it I opened the custom cell xib, and then on the right hand side Utilities I opened the File inspector tab (the tab to the far left). In there I could un-check "Use Autolayout".

Answer (score 0):

I created this exception by mistakenly registering the identifier with the wrong class type.

```
//The Identifier is register with the wrong class type
self.listView.register(CustomCellClass1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellClass2")
```

And then dequeuing and casting to a different class type:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellClass2", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellClass2
```