# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier error in my UITableView in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, ios6

I am getting this error in iOS 5

`-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa217200`

However, I get no errors in iOS 6. How can I fix this problem? Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; /// SIGABRT error

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
        initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
        reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Need your tableView delegate methods pasted here.

Comment: provide sufficient code to get answer

Answer (score 128, accepted):

**EDIT**: This method is newly added in iOS6+ SDK.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But in iOS 5, to create instance of `UITableViewCell` we generally use this method :-

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

In iOS 5, there is no need of extra parameter which you have used in iOS 6. (forIndexPath:).

So change your method. It will work.

Comment: Thanks Apple for making the default template code for a UITableViewController use an iOS6-only method without telling us!

Answer (score 7):

Here's why you're getting the error. As per the iOS 6.0 Documentation Set the UITableView Class Reference states  that  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is available in iOS 2.0 and later and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is available in iOS 6.0 and later.